# Is there a minimum of points that need to be $\epsilon$-close to a point to call this point a limit point?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, definition

I was thinking about the definition of a limit point and couldn't find a definition that contained any information if there is a minimum amount of points that need to be $\epsilon$-close to a point $x_0$ to call this point a limit point.

So I tried to come up with a sequence that could look something like that for example:

$$a_n:=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{n}, & n \not \in [m-1,m] \\
         x_0, & n= m \\
         x_0-\epsilon, & n=m-1\end{array}\right. \qquad n,m \in \mathbb{N}$$
*(First of all I am not sure if this is even a legitimate definition of a sequence, especially the $\epsilon$ in the defintion, not to mention the correctness of the notation.)*

If a sequence like this exists then this would be a null-sequence outside of the interval $[m-1,m]$ but would have a limit point at $x_0$.

Is this a correct statement or did I miss some details of the definition?

The definition I used was:

> A number $p \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of a set $M$, if for
>   every $\epsilon > 0$ an element $k \in M$ exists such that $k \neq p$
>   and $|k-p| < \epsilon$

---

Alternatively I also thought about defining a $\xi>0$ which is infinitely small and then write my sequence as $a_n:=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} ... \\
         x_0-\xi, & n=m-1\end{array}\right .$, so that I can get rid of the $\epsilon$ in my sequence definition. I just wanted to see if the usage of $\epsilon$ inside of a sequence is even allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your sequence depends on $\epsilon$, and therefore isn't a limit point.  Here's a fact:

> If $x_0$ is a limit point of some set $S$ and $x_0 \notin S$, then for each $\epsilon > 0$ there are infinitely many elements of $S$ within $\epsilon$ of $x_0$.

Why is this true?  We'll prove the contrapositive.  Suppose that $x_0$ is a limit point and there is some $\epsilon$ so that only finitely many members of $S$ are within $\epsilon$ of $x_0$.  Let's enumerate them, $s_1,\ldots,s_n$.  We may then set $\delta = \min_{1 \leq j \leq n} |x_0 - s_j|$ and note that $S$ has no elements within distance $\delta/2$ from $x_0$, i.e. $x_0$ is not a limit point.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for answering my question. However I still can't fully comprehend why the proof by contrapositive has to imply infinitely many members of $S$ and not just one member of $S$ that is infinitely close to a point $x_0$?

Comment: @MLK, that's because in the real numbers (and more generally any metric space) there's no notion of "infinitely close."  If $x \neq y$ are two points, then $|x - y| > 0$ is a number, and there is always a smaller positive number than that distance.

Comment: Ah well. So I just defined something that is not allowed to exist. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is one for each $\epsilon$.

Comment: But theoretically it could be the same value $x$ for every $\epsilon$?

Comment: @MLK, can $x\ne y$ and $x$ be $\epsilon$-close to $y$ for every $\epsilon >0$? (In a metric space, I assume?)

Comment: @jgon yes they can in this case